# Paypal Adaptive Payment on mobile

Tags: mobile, paypal-adaptive-payments

We're using chained payments and everything works fine on iOS-mobile devices,  we're making a web app, so we need this to work on phones.

the issue we are facing, is on non getting the option to pay by credit cards for guest users, 
the screen propose only Payment by Paypal account, we did follow many tutorials, that shows it works,

we did succeed to get it working by testing it with simple Paypal Express checkout,

but never succeeded when using Paypal Adaptive

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Comment: the question, is on how getting the Paypal Adaptive flow properly so that the buyer could get the option to pay also by credit card

in those tutorials, it suppose to work
this is the Ebay Article, which your tutorial

http://go.developer.ebay.com/devzone/articles/how-build-mobile-payments-system-paypal-and-qr-codes

and this is the Paypal Adaptive tutorial for Mobile :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/